# I need to write papers and publish but my supervisor wants me to do lab duties

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, supervision

I am doing my PhD since 2019 in the subject of molecular biology.
I am at the end stage of my PhD.

Despite the harsh beginning, I put really a lot of effort to become very good in laboratory work and I started spending a lot of time within the lab working at the bench within the 1st year of my PhD until now.

My supervisor was saying from the beginning that he wants us to release between 2-3 research articles + 1 review. And that he will help us with that.
Throughout my PhD, I was involved in 3-4 different projects.
Although, it was hard, I was really engaged in all of them because I remembered his words about the publications.

In addition to this, because we had no post-docs, I was responsible for the preparation of buffers and reagents, as well as the management of the stock in my lab.

Throughout my PhD there were another 3 students who were very negligible about the "condition" of our lab, thus whenever something was finished, they weren't bothered and I had to take care of that. In addition to this, many of them come very spontaneously to the lab, and sometimes they can come to the lab only  2-3 times throughout the whole week

Now, roughly 6 months before the finish of my stipend, during the lab meeting, he pointed out that the "lab members" have to start attending the lab regularly. His statement was a bit more elaborate, however, it made me feel like I am the one being targeted. In addition to this, I was then asked to come to the lab on some specific day to take care of the master's student and do the experiment. I said that "I cannot, because I want to focus on writing my thesis this week". He was all surprised and repeated to me I need to come to the lab.

I explained to him again that "at the beginning of the PhD I was told that there is a benchwork period and writing period, and now I want to focus on writing because I am lagging behind with that" (especially compared to the PhD students who haven't been coming to the lab that often).

Also meantime I was preparing some review articles. I sent it to him for some feedback, however, feedback wasn't very helpful, and usually was saying to add something more. Now I ended up with a big chunk of text, that I do not really know how to handle. I believe I need more help with that, but it is not coming.

I talked with him again recently, and I said that I am happy to still sacrifice some time for my "main" lab project because I hope to have it published. The supervisor said that the process is not that simple and it might take another 3-6 months before we manage to publish it.

I am not familiar with publication process or how to assemble a good "paper", because it is my first time doing it. And since I am a **PhD student**, I require some help with that.

On the end it seems like I spent 3 years, gathering data for my boss for different projects, while, he did not help me to publish anything not even a review paper which would make me more employable.

I will add that my supervisor had some conflicts with his employees which made them quit.

What should I do about this, should I forward an official complaint on him to the University. Or maybe I just complain too much?

Comment: In my opinion, from what you've written, an official complaint would not be justified (except there are more severe misconducts that you omitted?). However, you are justified in being dissatisfied with the poor supervision. You seem to be a diligent and mature person, but unfortunately your research group is not the best environment to thrive in.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind word. I feel so deceived and manipulated. I am so worried that without any paper I will not get any job or that my personal "impact factor" is very low...

Comment: What country? .

Answer (score 4):

I'm worried that stress has you overreacting. Note that fighting with your supervisor is usually counterproductive.

If you have been faithful about the lab then I'd guess that the criticism is directed at the others - or just general. He may feel that you have "taken charge" of the lab and so the words were directed at you. It would be fair if you were formally the lab manager, of course, but an overreaction otherwise.

But the big issue is your graduation. He says you have 3-6 months of work to go and you have 6 months of funding. So, it seems to fit.

Rather than make a complaint, I'd rather suggest that you seek his assurance that you will finish in a timely manner or have funding extended. If I read it more or less correctly then he is depending on you and that gives you the opportunity to get good recommendations if you don't poison the atmosphere.

But the bigger issue may well be stress. You've been at it hard for quite a while. If you can find a way to reduce that it might be made more comfortable, even though it remains hard.

Another big issue is the feedback on your writing and publications. You may need to meet with him more often with questions to make that go more smoothly. Just waiting for feedback (from a busy person) isn't going to improve it. One question you could ask, given that you aren't getting a lot of feedback, is whether he feels that feedback isn't really necessary and you are doing fine.

But, explore these things before you consider any formal complaints. That is likely to turn out badly.

Comment: Thank you. This is a valid point. Definitely, stress plays a big part in it, I do agree.
6 months of work might feet. However, It is another 6 months within the lab, in the time period when I should be writing. Of course, I will be still coming to the lab but more of in the ratio 40% - lab work 60% - office work/writing. But the supervisors still want me to look after the lab and students and take new projects "constantly".
About the feedback, yes maybe I should be more engaged. I just know that he is busy, and I hope that he remembers about me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I want to focus on the parts where you mention (fruitlessly) seeking advice.

First off, how independent PhD students are supposed to be is heavily country-dependent. In places where MSc is a requirement for PhD, the students are commonly assumed to have developed some writing skills already.

Most of the PhD students seem to get stuck at more or less the same things, which *usually* gets resolved by reviewing the work as if it's already being presented to the thesis committee or a harsh reviewer. Overall, be more proactive and specific when making arrangements and setting deadlines. "I ended up with a big chunk of text, that I do not really know how to handle" is not very helpful for them to diagnose possible issues. It is like

- Dear prof., I didn't understand, could you explain it a bit more, please?

- Sure, which part did you not understand?

- Could you, um, explain the entire thing?

It might be still on them to sort it out but you might be making it *very* complicated for them. Again, be specific: instead of "I don't know what to do with this" go for "I want to publish this, what are the obstacles preventing me from doing so?". With your supervisor put to the "reviewer" mode you might find their comments a lot more helpful (e.g. "The introductory section is absurdly short, a whole body of relevant work exists but only 5 articles are considered" instead of "please add more articles to the review part").

Unfortunately, no matter how hard you work it would not get you closer to even a single publication on its own. You must set it as a goal and work towards it.

> The supervisor said that the process is not that simple and it might take another 3-6 months before we manage to publicate it.

Depending on the exact meaning of this, it's either very quick or very slow: if you're only to submit it in half an year, that is slow, but you then need to work out what's lacking if you want it included in your thesis. You don't sound very involved with this project at the level above that of a lab technician at the moment - otherwise you would know the project scope and be able to reason about its current status: "we wanted to test X, we did, we have derived some conclusions from the data, I have prepared plots for publication and did the writing etc".

PhD supervisors LOVE to repeatedly tell students to not take their time with publishing because it takes a good while for the article to appear in print. What is barely covered, however, is how long does it take to prepare the article for submission - many researchers would do it under a week or even under a day. Supervisors absolutely don't get how clueless their students are about what makes it publishable in the first place. To that end...

> at the beginning of the PhD I was told that there is a benchwork period and writing period

This is not entirely a big fat lie, but something you almost surely misinterpreted. Yes, you will need some time *at the end* to assemble things together, tidy it up and do a bunch of writing. Given you're in a field with lots of lab work, setting aside 60% of the time to writing now is almost surely wasting most of that time. You would be much better off writing in short bursts, stumbling upon issues which would take you back to the lab anyway. Some people do need more time for writing, it's true, but you are presently doing this for the same reason you feel clueless about your review texts. This reason is that your writing is not really aligned with your goals, and probably a bit misaligned with the goals of your research for a good measure.

One more thing you might find helpful: every bit of your PhD is an answer to some question. Formulate these questions, they will help you structure your writing. Most general of them are:

- What problem are you trying to solve and why? (Thesis introduction, possible review article). Example: people love their grass green, but it is bleak.
- What has been done to solve this problem before? (Another part of introduction, review article). Example: Smith et al. tried to paint it, J. Doe used another cultivar of grass...
- What is your idea/approach? (First part of the main body of the thesis). Example: We've used autonomous hydroponic farming to control irrigation and nutrients supply.
- How did it turn out? What were the problems with this approach? (Results, Discussion, combined with the previous bit - an article or a few)
- How could your results be used/improved upon? (Conclusion)

This is still not specific at all. Suppose you've been working on molecular markers X for diagnosing Y. Why is diagnosing Y important? Currently, a completely different method Z is used to diagnose that, how does yours compare to it? How do you prove that? Why are your statistical tests valid? Are there other complications from using/creating X?

Go over existing articles in your field and mark every single paragraph with some question it attempts to answer. Do the same with your own writing. Devise more questions which need to be answered but are not.

Not knowing what to write or why, I would spend unlimited time with next to zero productivity. Don't get trapped in that, and good luck!